Book featuring a floating skull-shaped island
A pulp book read in the early 70s, but the only detail I can remember is that the protagonist went from Earth to another world where (somewhat like the movie Zardoz) the bad guys were headquartered on a mechanized water-borne floating island shaped like a skull.

Could this be a sci-fi pirate tale, as the skull-shaped island might suggest?

It may be a sci-fi pirate tale, but my memory is too hazy. I think the setup was something like Frederick Pohl's Guardians of Time, with (spoiler alert) the protagonist changing sides, but I can't be certain.
